# I want to find the number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ if not one element is in that position as in the original input $1 2 3 4 5 6$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

The answer given is $5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 1$.

I am trying to understand the solution. For the first position we must choose an element from the set $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$. Then for the next position we must choose from $\{1,3,4,5,6 \} - \{4\} = \{1,3,5,6\}$ assuming $4$ was chosen for the first position. etc.

I still do not feel comfortable with this. Maybe a different way to arrive at the same solution might be useful.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a particular element that cannot be in its correct position or that none of the elements can be in their original positions?  The answer at the top suggests that there is a particular number that cannot be placed in its original position, in which case that should be specified.

Comment: None of the elements can be in their "original" position. If 1 is in the first position, or 2 is in the second position, or 3 is in the third position... 214365 is a valid permutation but 124365 is not since 1 is in the first position.

Comment: The answer you've been given is an undercount of the correct answer.  For example say you had chosen 2 for the first position; then for the second position you'd have five possible choices, not four.  The number you're looking for is the number of "derangements" of a set of six elements.

Comment: Never heard of them. Thanks for introducing me to them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an application of derangement, in other words the permutation can have no fixed points. The formula for derangement of $n$ elements is: $!n=n!(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\ldots+(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n!})$.

Comment: Note that it is also equal to $\frac{n!}{e}$, rounded to nearest integer. With a calculator, this is a lot faster to calculate.

Comment: A more accurate formula is $\lfloor(n! + 1)/e\rfloor$.

Comment: "More accurate" how?